# Arduino Uno - minimize memory usage

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-uno-wifi

I have a Weather Meter, and I am able to read data from it.

My problem occurs, when I try to use the library UnoWiFiDevEd.h send the data to store the information on the internet.

Arduino tells following:

Global variables use 1648 bytes (80%) of dynamic memory, leaving 400 bytes for local variables.
Maximum is 2048 bytes. Low memory available, stability problems may occur.

I have read, that another means, that the Uno WiFi library itself leads almost 50% Dynamic Memory usage.

Do anyone have an idea, how I can minimize memory usage?

Thank you in advance

```
#include <UnoWiFiDevEd.h>

//temporary rain
float calcTemp1;
int calcTemp2;

//Wind vane
const float table[16] = {3.84, 1.98, 2.25, 0.41, 0.45, 0.32, 0.90, 0.62, 1.40, 1.19, 3.08, 2.93, 4.62, 4.32, 4.78, 3.43}; //charecter 13 is not correct, but is changed due to failure in windvane

char buffer[20];

//Anometer - windpower
volatile unsigned int windRotation = 0;
//Used for timing
float windTimer = 0;

int angle = 0;
//Rain gauge
float RainMeasurement = 0;
unsigned long LastRainReset = 0;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ciao.begin(); // CIAO INIT

  Serial.write(13);
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("Initialiserer...");
  initWind();
  initRain();
  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  doRequest();

  Serial.println();
  delay(30000);
} 


//Gets data about wind
void getWindData(void)
{
  Serial.print("Vindretning: ");
  Serial.println(printWindDirection(36));  

  unsigned long WindReading;
  WindReading = Vind_GetHastighed();
  sprintf(buffer, "Hastighed: %d m/s ", WindReading);
  Serial.println(buffer);
}


//Gets data about rain
void getRainData(void)
{
  if (LastRainReset+86400000 < millis()) { // LastRainReset > 24 timer
    RainMeasurement = 0;
    LastRainReset = millis();
  }

  calcTemp1 = (float)RainMeasurement;
  calcTemp2 = (calcTemp1 - (int)calcTemp1) * 100;
  sprintf(buffer, "%0d.%d", (int)calcTemp1, calcTemp2);
  Serial.print("Nedb\xF8r: ");
  Serial.print(buffer);
  Serial.println(" mm");
}

void doRequest(){
  String resource = "upload.php?key=secretKey";
  resource += "&windDir=";
  resource += String(angle);
  getWindData();
  resource += "&windSpeed=";
  resource += String(Vind_GetHastighed());
  resource += "&rainAmount=";
  getRainData();
  resource += String(buffer);
  Serial.println(resource);
  CiaoData data = Ciao.write("rest", "http://example.com/", resource, "GET");
  if (!data.isEmpty()){
    Ciao.println( "Link: " + String (resource) );
    Ciao.println( "State: " + String (data.get(1)) );
    Ciao.println( "Response: " + String (data.get(2)) );
    Ciao.println();
  }
  else{
    Ciao.println ("Write Error");
    Ciao.println();
  }
}

// Initializing processes 
void initWind(void)
{
  pinMode(3, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(1, windSpeed, RISING);
  windTimer=millis();//start timing  
  Serial.println("* Vindretning");
  Serial.println("* Vindhastighed");
}

//initializing rainmeasure
void initRain(void)
{
  attachInterrupt(0, Rain_Measure, RISING); //analog port 0
  LastRainReset = millis();
  Serial.println("* Regn");
}    

//Counts amount of rain
void Rain_Measure(void)
{
  volatile byte hit = 1;
  if (hit == 1) {
    hit = 2;
  } else if (hit == 2) {
    hit = 3;
  } else if (hit == 3) {
    RainMeasurement = RainMeasurement + 0.2794;
    hit = 1;
  }  
}

//Prints winddirection
String printWindDirection(byte y)
{
   // read the analog input into a variable:
   String windDir = "unknown";
   float voltage = analogRead(0)/204.6;   
   for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
     if (voltage <= table[i]+0.03 && voltage >= table[i]-0.03) {
       angle = i;
       break;
     }
   } 
   //Serial.println(angle); //print the result
   switch (angle) {
     case 0:
       windDir = "N";
       break;
     case 1:
       windDir = "NNE";
       break;       
     case 2:
       windDir = "NE";
       break;       
     case 3:
       windDir = "E";
       break;       
     case 4:
       windDir = "E";
       break;       
     case 5:
       windDir = "E";
       break;       
     case 6:
       windDir = "SE";  
       break;       
     case 7:
       windDir = "SSE";
       break;       
     case 8:
       windDir = "S";
       break;       
     case 9:
       windDir = "SW";
       break;       
     case 10:
       windDir = "SW";
       break;       
     case 11:
       windDir = "WSW";
       break;       
     case 12:
       windDir = "W";
       break;       
     case 13:
       windDir = "WNW";
       break;       
     case 14:
       windDir = "NW";
       break;       
     case 15:
       windDir = "NNW";
       break;        
     default:
       break;
   }
   return windDir;
}  

//Prints windspeed
int Vind_GetHastighed()
{
  /*
  The cup-type anemometer measures wind speed by closing a contact as 
  a magnet moves past a switch.  A wind speed of 1.492 MPH (2.4 km/h) 
  causes the switch to close once per second.
  */ 

  //Check using Interrupt
  float windDtime =  millis()-windTimer;
  windTimer = millis();
  windDtime = windDtime/1000;
  float windSpeed = windRotation/windDtime;//rotation per second
  windRotation = 0;  
  windSpeed = windSpeed*2/3;//1 rotation per second equals 2.4 km/h = 2/3 m/s
  return int(windSpeed);
}

void windSpeed()
{
  windRotation++;
}
```

Comment: why the [java] tag? use F macro for constant strings https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/#_the_code_f_code_macro

Comment: if you one day want to do more with your Uno WiFi Dev Ed, bookmark this link https://github.com/jandrassy/UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1/blob/master/README.md

Comment: `const float table[16]` can be reduced by 48 bytes, if you compare to the values of `byte winddir = analogRead(0)/4;` Not using String objects saves even more RAM than you can see at compile time.

Comment: @Juraj I have removed the Java-tag, it was a mistake.
Thanks for the links to the extended Uno Wifi Dev. library

@datafiddler I have changed the `const float table[16]` to `const float table[48]`. I have also changed return type of the method printWindDirection(byte y) and the local variable windDir to byte. The program now returns: Sketch uses 15360 bytes (47%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 1776 bytes (86%) of dynamic memory, leaving 272 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
Low memory available, stability problems may occur.

Comment: @Juraj Would you write your F macro as answer, so the question can be closed. Although, it some times returns Write error, it always commits data on my DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino has [the F() macro](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/#_the_code_f_code_macro) for constant strings to simply indicate that the string should be used from the 'ROM' flash memory of Harvard architecture CPU and not loaded into 'dynamic memory' (RAM). By wrapping constant strings into F macro you reduce the usage of RAM.